# Why function is not working when I try to get name ? PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

Now I am on probation, and my supervisor gave me such an assignment.
Although he knows that I do not understand PL/SQL

The essence of the task:
The function receives the client's ID as input and returns name.

Also, this code needs to be optimized.
Besides that this code doesn't work, what needs to be done to optimize it and make it work?

Sorry for a possibly stupid question.

At the moment I am studying PL/SQL, but my knowledge is not enough to understand the functions.

**Table without constraints and primary keys.**

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER, CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR2(255));


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_name(customer_id number)
return varchar2
as
result varchar2(50);
BEGIN
    select customer_name
    into result
    from customers c
    where c.customers_id = customers_id;
    return result;
END;
```

*Sorry for my bad English.*

Comment: Just a caution. Your function gets the customer name, but that column on the database is up to 255 bytes, but your function (result variable)  only allows for 50). Any name over 50 will throw an error, that means a valid value on the database can cause an error. Be safe, set your local variables at least as large as the database allows. Even better actually anchor your local variables to the database column. In this case instead of "result varchar2(255)" use **result customers.customer_name%type**.

Comment: If either of the answers provided solved you issue then please accept it. If not then indicate the problem with them. Do not however just leave the question as Open and Unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

Code you wrote is *almost* OK. Two errors you made:

- if column name is `CUSTOMER_ID`, then don't reference it as `CUSTOMERS_ID`
- if column name is `CUSTOMERS_ID`, don't name function's **parameter** the same because - when used in `WHERE` clause - Oracle can't distinguish what is what so this:

  ```
  where customers_id = customers_id
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  where 1 = 1
  ```

  which is not what you wanted.

Here's an example which shows how to do it; see if it helps.

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table customers as select empno customers_id, ename customer_name
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno = 10;

Table created.
```

Function; note changed parameter name:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_name(par_customers_id number)
  2  return varchar2
  3  as
  4  result varchar2(50);
  5  BEGIN
  6      select customer_name
  7      into result
  8      from customers c
  9      where c.customers_id = par_customers_id;
 10      return result;
 11  END;
 12  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select customers_id, get_name(customers_id) name
  2  from customers;

CUSTOMERS_ID NAME
------------ --------------------
        7782 CLARK
        7839 KING
        7934 MILLER

SQL>
```

So far so good, is it not?

---

How to use the `DUAL` table?

```
SQL> select get_name(7782) from dual;

GET_NAME(7782)
----------------------------------------
CLARK

SQL>
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your help.
But based on the examples that you gave.
If I enter the client ID, then I should only get his name and ID.
And when I start a request, if I add ID to the get name, I get all clients, it also happens if I specify the client ID (1, 2, 3).
Example:
select customer_id, get_name(customers_id) name
from customers;
OR:
select customer_id, get_name(1) name
from customers;
OR:
select customer_id, get_name(1) name
from customers;
I get the same result every time.
But every time I enter a different ID, I have to get the corresponding name.
What's wrong :( ?

Comment: Select from DUAL, not from CUSTOMERS

Comment: Sorry, I tried to do this, but it seems I did not understand how to use dual in this case.
Could you write what to do to display information according to the comment above.
Thank you in advance and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I added the DUAL table example; have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Your function has no exception handling and are you sure that select is returning only single value.

Because if its not then function will throw the error and hence function will not perform as expected as there is no exception handling.

Execute below query in sql developer to identify how many customer ids have more than one record in the table.

```
select customers_id, count(1)
    from customers c
group by customers_id;
```